# How to immediately tell if location manager has failed to get location in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to check if location is available before proceeding to another view. But unless

```
locationManager:didFailWithError:
```

is called, I can't know if location service has become unavailable.

What I did is to `start` and `stop` location service to manually check failure and call a callback block then to present the view. But the problem is it might take up to several seconds to determine location availability.

So what is the best way to immediately tell if location manager has failed to get location?

Comment: You can't, location is an async process. You need to wait that one of the callbacks is called

Comment: It is worth mentioning that checking the [`authorizationStatus`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/authorizationStatus) on CLLocationManager class can help you partially, as if the authorization is "Denied", then the manager will almost certainly fail. This means that if it is impossible for you to obtain a location due to permissions, then that can be detected beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you use `didFailWithError` is the right way to go. It responds to you if the location isn't available anymore.

I don't think that there is another way of doing it faster. What you could try is that you use the [`didUpdateLocations`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateLocations:) method and check the location in there if it's `nil`

```
var newLocation = map.userLocation
var locationAvailable:Bool!
if let theLocation = newLocation.location{
    locationAvailable = true
}else{
    locationAvailable = false
}
```